# How to create a redux store with local data storage?

Tags: redux, local-storage, redux-middleware, redux-storage

I am confused by the docs. I am trying to use [Redux-storage](https://github.com/react-stack/redux-storage) middleware and this is how they show the store is created with the middleware:

```
const middleware = storage.createMiddleware(engine);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(middleware)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
```

But the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#arguments) show this:

```
let store = createStore(
  todos,
  [ 'Use Redux' ], // How do I put here the data from the redux-storage?
  applyMiddleware(middleware) // here goes the redux-storage
)
```

`createStore` requires an initial store value to be passed, but I can't load the stored values without having a store. This is a kind of catch 22. What did I miss here?

Answer (score 2):

You actually miss nothing and that is intended behavior of `redux-storage`: there is a gap between creating redux store and the moment it got filled with the stored data. That is because storage engine provided to `redux-storage` `createLoader` can have an async nature in general case.

The common pattern to deal with that is following:

1. Your app starts up with uninitialized store state
2. It shows some kind of a preloader to your user
3. App creates loader and loads stored state: `const load = storage.createLoader(engine); load(store);`
4. Wait store to be rehydrated and hide preloader.

There is another store peristing lib out there: [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). But initialization process works the same way, except you don't have to call `load` explicitly.

Comment: Thanx, but I am still confused about how to actually use the API, can you show a code example?